# Eclipse doclet plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javadoc, doclet

I'm looking for an Eclipse javadoc doclet plugin that modifies the standard *built in* javadoc generation process. In other words, I would like to specify custom tags and maybe use wiki syntax or whatever in a normal javadoc comment and have the generated output show up in those popups that appear when hovering over a method or a class identifier.

To be clear, I am *not* looking for a way to specify a doclet when explicitly generating external javadoc.

It seems that Eclipse uses some internal mechanism to generate the popup javadoc and in the past hour of googling I wasn't able to find a plugin that modifies that behaviour.

Any ideas or pointers? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know much about Eclipse, but could it be that it simply parses the HTML output from Javadoc?

Comment: I think it has some internal parsing engine; you can't specify doclets when generating the popup javadoc.